# R: sort using probabilities calculated from vector values

Tags: r

Given a vector, say `c(1, 2, 3)`, I'd like to generate samples of this vector sorted according to probabilities calculated from its values.  The process is illustrated below - is there an R function that does this?

A simple example, use probabilities calculated as the value divided by the vector sum: `c(1/6, 2/6, 3/6)` to determine the first value in the sorted vector.  In this case value `3` has probability `3/6` or 50% of being the first element, value `2` has probability `2/6` or 33.3% of being the first element and `1` has probability `1/6` or 16.6%.

After the first element is selected, the process continues similarly for the remaining elements of the vector until a 'statistically' ordered vector is produced.

As the number of 'statistically' ordered samples grows, I'd expect `3` to be first 50% of the time, etc.  A mocked up example of a sample size 6:

```
c(3, 2, 1)
c(2, 3, 1)
c(3, 1, 2)
c(3, 2, 1)
c(1, 3, 2)
c(2, 1, 3)
```

Comment: `prop.table(1:3)`

Comment: Hopefully the mocked up example helps, I'm after the samples, not the probabilities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sample(1:3, prob = 1:3, replace = FALSE)
```

testing it:

```
set.seed(42)
res <- replicate(1e5, sample(1:3, prob = 1:3, replace = FALSE))

prop.table(table(res[1,]))
#      1       2       3 
#0.16620 0.33324 0.50056
prop.table(table(res[2,]))
#      1       2       3 
#0.25026 0.39827 0.35147
prop.table(table(res[3,]))
#      1       2       3 
#0.58354 0.26849 0.14797
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
N <- 100
X <- 3
replicate(N, sample(X, prob=prop.table(1:X)))
```

Output

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14]
[1,]    3    3    3    3    3    1    3    3    3     3     2     3     2     2
[2,]    2    1    2    2    1    3    1    1    1     1     3     2     1     3
[3,]    1    2    1    1    2    2    2    2    2     2     1     1     3     1
# etc
```

You can `transpose` the output if you prefer

```
t(replicate(N, sample(X, prob=prop.table(1:X))))
```